# edgedriver delete cookie failed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am using an edge driver, but deleting cookies failed.

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Here is the stack:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: Does your browser start? If yes does it pass if you comment this line. I'm trying to understand if the error is related to deleteCookies method at all or a general browser issue?

Comment: If you add full details of stacktrace, versions (selenium, browser) would be helpful.